# RFC subsystem not yet initialized

Tags: saprfc, sap-r3

I have installed saprfc-1.4.1 on linux 4.0.4-x86_64 (ubuntu14) machine.

**PHP Version 5.5.9**

**RFCSDK 7.20**

After installation, I added the extension (`extension = saprfc.so`) in php.ini file and then restarted apache.

To test if installation was successful i uploaded saprfc_test.php to my www directory.

**Entered following details to login to SAP R/3**

```
Application Server          - localhost
System Number               - 00
Client                      - 300
User                        - myusername
Password                    - *********
Message Server              - MSPLECP00_ECP_00
R/3 system Name             - ECP
Language                    - EN
```

When i tried to Login i got following error:

```
RFC Error Info : Key : RFC_NOT_INIT Status : 
Message : RFC subsystem not yet initialized. Internal:
```

Comment: Without a lot more details, it's unlikely you'll get a suitable answer

Comment: i have edited my question